Firebase Authentication on Flutter Web with Phone Number
I'm using Firebase Authentication in my Flutter app with the following library versions:

firebase_auth: 4.20.0
firebase_core: 2.17.0
The setup works perfectly on iOS and Android. However, on the web, I'm encountering an INVALID_APP_CREDENTIALerror. I have already created reCAPTCHA site keys and added the site secret key to my Firebase project. And I'm encoutring this in "verifyPhoneNumber".
Any suggestions on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated!

I followed the Firebase documentation for setting up phone authentication with reCAPTCHA on the web. Specifically:

I created the reCAPTCHA site keys in the Google reCAPTCHA admin console.
I added the site secret key to the Firebase project settings in the Firebase console for Web Project.
I verified the domain whitelisting in Firebase Authentication > Settings > Authorized domains.

I expected reCAPTCHA verification to work seamlessly, but instead, I got an INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL error. Could you provide guidance on what might be wrong or how to debug this further?"

Are you seeing the reCAPTCHA show up? When does the INVALID_APP_CREDENTIAL error occur? Setup docs: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone#web-signinwithphonenumber

That is an old documentation link. Now, reCAPTCHA uses v3 which is invisible. It stays invisible but sometimes we can see the widget, which is very rare.
